# Flutter TTS Pitch Not Changing

Tags: flutter, dart, text-to-speech

I am trying to use flutter text to speech on my app and I want to give users the ability to choose the voice pitch they want (male or female) but it does not change, it only speaks the default female voice pitch. I have tried to put in the pitch manually or set it up again but it only speaks the default voice.

Here is how I set it up. I have FluterTTS declared at the top in my class then the function to speak :

```
speak(String newVoiceText) async {
    await flutterTTs.setLanguage('en-AU');
    await flutterTTs.setPitch(2.0); //Ranges for 0.5 to 2.0
    await flutterTTs.speak(newVoiceText);
  }
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Which version do you use and on which device do you test?

Comment: Looks like this issue: https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts/issues/347 - can you try an older version and test it also on different devices

Comment: I am currently using version 3.5.0 and I used a physical device, a samsung tablet to test. It speaks but doesn't change. 

Okay thanks, I'll check out that question right away. I have used the version 3.5 before as well.

Comment: @Ozan From link, it seems like the API has some issues and has not been fixed yet.